# Understanding ACTUATOR role in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

After recent spring boot upgrade (1.5+) I am no longer able to access /metrics endpoint in my application. To solve this, I added management.security.enabled=false and management.security.roles=ACTUATOR. This allowed me to access the endpoint and it still required credentials before viewing. This works but I don’t understand why. Am I only disabling the ACTUATOR role to access this endpoint? Is there any security risk here?

Answer (score 0):

I know after you move to spring boot 2.0.0.M5 only status and info endpoints are enabled by default. In Spring Boot 2 also you no longer need to have management.security.enabled https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11383

I generally use this:

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info, health, metrics, env, beans, configprops

Comment: Thanks! I will try this but do you see any issue with my approach from a security standpoint?